# Is it possible to navigate to the 6th svg tag and then the 4th g tag to get the text of '35'?

Tags: python, selenium

[The text '35' is what I am interested of capturing. (It is always the 6th svg tag followed by 4th g tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn8lM.png)

```
My code:

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='div' and @id='chartContainer']//*[name()= 'svg' and @style= 'position: absolute; z-index: 6;']//*[name()= 'g' and @font-size= '10pt]")
driver.quit()
print(value)
```

[website url][2]

**Error message:** *

> InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate
> an element with the xpath expression //*[name()='div' and
> @id='chartContainer']//*[name()= 'svg' and @style= 'position:
> absolute; z-index: 6;']//*[name()= 'g' and @font-size= '10pt] because
> of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on
> 'Document': The string '//*[name()='div' and
> @id='chartContainer']//*[name()= 'svg' and @style= 'position:
> absolute; z-index: 6;']//*[name()= 'g' and @font-size= '10pt]' is not
> a valid XPath expression.   (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)

- 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can point to 6th svg and 4th g tag like that :

```
((//div[@id='chartContainer']//*[name()='svg'])[6]//*[name()='g'])[4]//*[name()='text']
```

In code :

```
value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//div[@id='chartContainer']//*[name()='svg'])[6]//*[name()='g'])[4]//*[name()='text']").text
print(value)
```

Please put some explicit waits as well before interaction.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//div[@id='chartContainer']//*[name()='svg'])[6]//*[name()='g'])[4]//*[name()='text']").text
print(value)
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
value = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "((//div[@id='chartContainer']//*[name()='svg'])[6]//*[name()='g'])[4]//*[name()='text']"))).text
print(value)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: Hello there cruisepandey. TQVM for the help!

`from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`  
`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`  
`from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`  

`value = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "((//div[@id='chartContainer']//*[name()='svg'])[6]//*[name()='g'])[4]//*[name()='text']"))).text`  
`print(value)`  

this code works

Comment: Code trial 1 with the time.sleep works too, however, one need to change it to time.sleep(2). As I have tested, time.sleep(5) will give an error which I believe to be caused by the print screen auto pop up.

Comment: `time.sleep()` practice has been discouraged, Pleas use Webdriverwait, code trial 2 from my solution.

Answer (score 0):

`'` is missing at last of your `xPath` expression.

```
value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='div' and @id='chartContainer']//*[name()= 'svg' and @style= 'position: absolute; z-index: 6;']//*[name()= 'g' and @font-size= '10pt']")
```

But the above `xPath` what you have written points to 6th `svg` tag and the 6th `g` tag.

You need to use either any one of the below `xPath` to point 6th `svg` and 4th `g` tag.

```
//*[name()='div' and @id='chartContainer']//*[name()= 'svg' and @style= 'position: absolute; z-index: 6;']//*[name()= 'g' ][4]
```

Or

```
//*[name()='div' and @id='chartContainer']//*[name()= 'svg'][6]//*[name()= 'g' ][4]
```

Comment: Hello Nandan, thank you for the help !

The code works, however, we need to add time.sleep(2) before that.

I've tried time.sleep(5), it says unable to find the element, and I believe this is due to the print screen which automatically pops up.